# Java translate reflection-invoked program's file API paths

Tags: java, filesystems, virtual-machine, chroot, java.nio.file

I am trying to implement something like virtual machine in Java. Yes, it NEEDS
to be made in java, since it wraps some already-coded java library and implements
it's abstractions. But on the problem...

The actual problem is that it is intended to run java programs written to be run
on UNIX platforms (e.g. They need to log to /var/log). I can load the jar, and launch it by invoking main method... But the real problem lies that whenever the file tries to access the filesystem, it crashes because the filesystem is not in proper format (e.g. It is missing /var/volatile as it is used commonly on embedded systems but rarely on full desktops). I am looking for a solution to translate default Java java.nio.File abstract pathnames to some other locations, or to make virtual FS in a file (like loop device), or anything similar, that would work like chroot for the program. I couldn't find a single soultion to this problem around the web. The real reason behind that is to allow users of **any** platform to run the VM **without** modifing the source code of the program being run in the VM.

Many Thanks.

Comment: You can set the system property `java.nio.file.spi.DefaultFileSystemProvider` to denote which `FileSystemProvider` will be the default, i.e. also used for backing up `java.io.File`. However, you have to find or implement such virtual file system first.

Comment: I have already tried that. I implemented it, but the abstract paths were translated only when calling `File#toPath()`. Nevermind, I discovered it's impossible because of JRE internal structure.